# How to move from deprecated Task to ApiFuture for firebase admin SDK 5.4 and above

Tags: java, firebase, java-8, firebase-admin

I'm just trying to solve the deprecation notes from my Java code of new firebase-admin SDK, the code is written in version 5.3.1 but after upgrading the version into 5.5.0 the deprecation notes appeared, here is a sample of my code:

Using **FirebaseAuth** (deprecatation on: `Task`, `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener`) :

```
private CompletableFuture<FirebaseToken> getDecryptedTokenCompletableFuture(String firebaseTokenString) {
        CompletableFuture<FirebaseToken> tokenFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        Task<FirebaseToken> tokenTask = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(firebaseApp).verifyIdToken(firebaseTokenString);
        tokenTask.addOnSuccessListener(tokenFuture::complete);
        tokenTask.addOnFailureListener(exception -> tokenFuture.completeExceptionally(new AuthorizationException("Failed to verify token", exception)));
        return tokenFuture;
    }
```

And for **FirebaseDatabase** (deprecatation on: `Task`, `addOnSuccessListener`, `addOnFailureListener`, `updateChildren` and `removeValue`) :

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> toCompletableFuture(Task<T> task) {
    CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    task.addOnCompleteListener(result -> {
        future.complete(result.getResult());
    }).addOnFailureListener(future::completeExceptionally);
    return future;
}

/**
 * @param updatedParams if null it will removed child
 * @param path          path to update
 * @return void when complete
 */
public CompletableFuture<Void> updateObjectData(Map<String, Object> updatedParams, String path) {
    if (updatedParams == null) {
        return removeObjectData(path);
    }
    logger.debug("Update ObjectData in firebase of ref ({}) with data: {}", path, updatedParams.toString());
    DatabaseReference child = this.getUserDataReference().child(path);
    return toCompletableFuture(child.updateChildren(updatedParams));
}

/**
 * @param path path to of node to remove
 * @return void when complete
 */
public CompletableFuture<Void> removeObjectData(String path) {
    logger.debug("Remove ObjectData in firebase of ref ({})", path);
    DatabaseReference child = this.getUserDataReference().child(path);
    return toCompletableFuture(child.removeValue());
}
```

The deprecation note saying I have to use `ApiFuture` as what the release notes saying: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java

And inside source, as for example:

> ```
>   /**
>    * Similar to {@link #updateChildrenAsync(Map)} but returns a Task.
>    *
>    * @param update The paths to update and their new values
>    * @return The {@link Task} for this operation.
>    * @deprecated Use {@link #updateChildrenAsync(Map)}
>    */
> ```

And

> ```
> /**
>  * Represents an asynchronous operation.
>  *
>  * @param <T> the type of the result of the operation
>  * @deprecated {@code Task} has been deprecated in favor of
>  *     <a href="https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/1.1.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFuture.html">{@code ApiFuture}</a>.
>  *     For every method x() that returns a {@code Task<T>}, you should be able to find a
>  *     corresponding xAsync() method that returns an {@code ApiFuture<T>}.
>  */
> ```

Comment: Have you tried looking into the new API at all to learn how it works?

Comment: @DougStevenson if you mean this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin or https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android the document seems still for old version and not updated yet if you mean `addListener(Runnable listener, Executor executor)` this is what I'm asking for what the `Runnable listener` or let's say how I can do `toCompletableFuture` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost 2 years, but need to add my answers, current answers gave me a guide but were not a full solution, so Kudos for `@Enylton Machado` and `@Hiranya Jayathilaka` it is still good to refer to their answers, give them upvotes.

Currently, I did change `toCompletableFuture` to:

```
public <T> CompletableFuture<T> toCompletableFuture(ApiFuture<T> apiFuture) {
    final CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    apiFuture.addListener(() -> {
        try {
            future.complete(apiFuture.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            future.completeExceptionally(ex);
        }
    }, executionContext);
    return future;
}
```

Where `executionContext` got injected in the constructor, since I'm using Play Framework, or you can initialize your own using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` as for example! but you need to handle shutting down it and other stuff, more details can be learned from here [ExecutorService in Java](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/executor-service-example/) or [A Guide to the Java ExecutorService](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial).

So when I do call like `this.getUserDataReference().child(path).push().setValueAsync(value)`, I do call it like:

```
public CompletableFuture<String> pushDataToArray(String path, Map<String, Object> paramsToAdd) {
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = getUserDataReference().child(path).push();
    paramsToAdd.put("createdAt", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    return toCompletableFuture(databaseReference.setValueAsync(paramsToAdd), this.executionContext)
            .thenApply(voidResult -> databaseReference.getKey());
}
```

**Edit**: if you prefer use `ApiFutures`:

```
public <T> CompletableFuture<T> toCompletableFuture(ApiFuture<T> apiFuture) {
    final CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    ApiFutures.addCallback(apiFuture, new ApiFutureCallback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            future.completeExceptionally(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(T result) {
            try {
                future.complete(apiFuture.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                logger.error(ex.getMessage());
                future.completeExceptionally(ex);
            }
        }
    }, executionContext);
    return future;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The code to verify a Token with FirebaseAuth from Firebase Admin SDK Java using ApiFuture, would be:

```
ApiFutures.addCallback(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdTokenAsync(token),
  new ApiFutureCallback<FirebaseToken>() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        // TODO handle failure
      }
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
        // TODO handle success
      }
});
```

Similar approach can be used for your code that uses FirebaseDatabase.

Hiranya Jayathilaka wrote a very detailed article explaining how to migrate from Task to ApiFuture and the rational behind it: https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-asynchronous-operations-with-admin-java-sdk-82ca9b4f6022

This code works for versions 5.4.0 - 5.8.0, the most recent at the time of this writing. 
The release notes are available here: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [`ApiFutures`](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/0.2.0/apidocs/index.html?com/google/api/core/ApiFutures.html) util class, which allows adding callbacks to an `ApiFuture`.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check this out

Comment: Nice answer, guy! Thanks!